# How to test relationship between weight gain due to a drug

Tags: anova

Im running an experiment and im not sure what stats Test should i use. I have 2 groups of male mice  (n=9) where one group will recieve a drug dose, and the other one won't. My goal here is to understand the effect of the drug on weight during the experiment.

For example: Day 1. Ctrl vs Drug, Day 2 Ctrl vs Drug Day 3 Ctrl vs Drug.... and so on, until the end of the experiment.
I was thinking about a one Way ANOVA, but when i enter the data to SPSS it only compares me for ex.  DAY 1 CTRL vs DAY 2 CTRL, VS DAY 3 CTRL and so on, it only compares within the same group.  Something like this, in 40, 80, 120 he compares both groups.

[image]

I hope someone can help me, and excuse my incorrect english, its not my native language.

Comment: So you have two groups drug vs no drug and three measurements over time? I guess the dosage of drug is the same for all mice in the drug group, or are you looking for dose-response relationships? Are there any additional factors/variables that you need to consider?

Comment: sorry i never received a notification about an answer. The drug group received the same dose all the experiment. I just posted an example of a graph but mine is during 15 days. So i guess it might be a dose response relationship, those are the only variables.

Comment: Please register &/or merge your accounts (you can find information on how to do 
this in the **My Account** section of our [help]), then you will be able to 
edit & comment on your own question.

Comment: Please [merge](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) your accounts https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/166197/isaac and https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/169220/isaac ... this would be why you didn't get notified -- you're using a different account than the one you posted from